Pyright cannot guess data type in polymorphic python function
The problem should be pretty simple. I have a function accepting dictionaries where the values must be of type float, int or numpy.ndarray. I can use ArrayLike type.
Inside, i have two functions handling specifically scalar values (float, int) or array values.
Here's a code sample:
from typing import Dict, Union, Mapping
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def fun_for_float(data: dict[str, Union[float,int]]) -> None:
    pass

def fun_for_array(data: dict[str, np.ndarray]) -> None:
    pass

def main_function(data: dict[str, ArrayLike]) -> None:
    if all(isinstance(val, Union[float,int]) for val in data.values()):
        return fun_for_float(data)
    elif all(isinstance(val, np.ndarray) for val in data.values()):
        return fun_for_array(data)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Values in the dictionary must be float or np.ndarray.")


Problem is, pyright seams not understanding my type guards.
I get the following error:
Argument of type "dict[str, ArrayLike]" cannot be assigned to parameter "data" of type "dict[str, float | int]" in function "fun_for_float"
  "dict[str, ArrayLike]" is incompatible with "dict[str, float | int]"
    Type parameter "_VT@dict" is invariant, but "ArrayLike" is not the same as "float | int"
    Consider switching from "dict" to "Mapping" which is covariant in the value type

Now, I get the point. Dict use invariant values, ok. ArrayLike surely is not the same thing as float or int, but float and int should be contained in it and trough the if statements, pyrigth should be able to narrow the type of data.
Anyway, I followed pyright suggestion and used Mapping.
def fun_for_float(data: Mapping[str, Union[float,int]]) -> None:
    pass

def fun_for_array(data: Mapping[str, np.ndarray]) -> None:
    pass

def main_function(data: Mapping[str, ArrayLike]) -> None:
    if all(isinstance(val, Union[float,int]) for val in data.values()):
        return fun_for_float(data)
    elif all(isinstance(val, np.ndarray) for val in data.values()):
        return fun_for_array(data)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Values in the dictionary must be float or np.ndarray.")


This is what I got.
Argument of type "Mapping[str, ArrayLike]" cannot be assigned to parameter "data" of type "Mapping[str, float | int]" in function "fun_for_float"
  "Mapping[str, ArrayLike]" is incompatible with "Mapping[str, float | int]"
    Type parameter "_VT_co@Mapping" is covariant, but "ArrayLike" is not a subtype of "float | int"

Now, without type guards pyright would be 100% right and it should complaint. ArrayLike is definitely not a sub set of Union[float | int], it's true the opposite.
Two reasons may explain the error:

(less likely) pyright cannot understand the all(isinstance()...)kind of type check.
(more likely) I messed up and I'm missing something.

Any suggestion?

I accidentally solved the problem shortly after the question was posted.
I leave the answer here should anyone need it.
Let's say that both possibilities were true somewhat. Pyright cannot autonomously interpret the all(asinstance()) construct. And I messed up not knowing you can define explicite TypeGuards (my fault for not reading the documentation).
To help pyright, one can construct explicit type guards.
Here an even simpler example
def is_float(data: List[int|float]) -> TypeGuard[List[float]]:
    return all(isinstance(val, float) for val in data)

def is_int(data: List[int|float]) -> TypeGuard[List[int]]:
    return all(isinstance(val,int) for val in data)

def handle_int_list(data: List[int]) -> None:
    pass

def handle_float_list(data: List[float]) -> None:
    pass
def process_data(data: List[Union[int, float]]) -> None:
    if is_int(data):
        handle_int_list(data)
    elif is_float(data):
        handle_float_list(data)
    else:
        print("Data contains mixed types")



Just FTR, in 3.13+ this should use TypeIs.
